Check is CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS is set for a connection
I maintain a library, which uses a database connection provided by user (golang's *sql.DB). Is it possible to extract this information from an existing connection e.g. using some kind of SELECT query?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/9.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html
